# ¿Cómo personalizar el email de restablecimiento de contraseña enviado en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera cambiar el texto mostrado en el mensaje y también la `url`.

**El mensaje que recibo es este:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; color: #74787E; height: 100%; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-word-break: break-all; width: 100% !important; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; word-break: break-word;">
    <style>
        @media  only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .inner-body {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media  only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .button {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td class="header" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://localhost" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #bbbfc3; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;">
            Laravel
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Email Body --><tr>
<td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEFF2; border-top: 1px solid #EDEFF2; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                            <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
<!-- Body content --><tr>
<td class="content-cell" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                                        <h1 style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #2F3133; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Hola!</h1>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.</p>
<table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 30px auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;"><tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <a href="http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" class="button button-blue" target="_blank" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #FFF; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3097D1; border-top: 10px solid #3097D1; border-right: 18px solid #3097D1; border-bottom: 10px solid #3097D1; border-left: 18px solid #3097D1;">Reset Password</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr></table>
</td>
                </tr></table>
</td>
    </tr></table>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.</p>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Regards,<br>Laravel</p>
<table class="subcopy" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border-top: 1px solid #EDEFF2; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 25px;"><tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 12px;">If you’re having trouble clicking the "Reset Password" button, copy and paste the URL below
into your web browser: <a href="http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #3869D4;"></a><a href="http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #3869D4;">http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr></table>
</td>
                                </tr>
</table>
</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;"><tr>
<td class="content-cell" align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                    <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">© 2017 Laravel. All rights reserved.</p>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
        </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**A mi me gustaría editarlo para enviar algo como esto (notece que también cambio la url):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; color: #74787E; height: 100%; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-word-break: break-all; width: 100% !important; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; word-break: break-word;">
    <style>
        @media  only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .inner-body {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media  only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .button {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td class="header" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://localhost" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #bbbfc3; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;">
            Laravel
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Email Body --><tr>
<td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEFF2; border-top: 1px solid #EDEFF2; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                            <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
<!-- Body content --><tr>
<td class="content-cell" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                                        <h1 style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #2F3133; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Hola!</h1>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Recibió este correo electrónico porque recibimos una solicitud de restablecimiento de contraseña para su cuenta.</p>
<table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 30px auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;"><tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                                    <a href="http://sistema.local/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" class="button button-blue" target="_blank" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #FFF; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3097D1; border-top: 10px solid #3097D1; border-right: 18px solid #3097D1; border-bottom: 10px solid #3097D1; border-left: 18px solid #3097D1;">Reinicio de contraseña</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr></table>
</td>
                </tr></table>
</td>
    </tr></table>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Si no solicitó una contraseña de restablecimiento, no se requiere ninguna acción adicional.</p>
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Saludos,<br>Laravel</p>
<table class="subcopy" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border-top: 1px solid #EDEFF2; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 25px;"><tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 12px;">Si tiene problemas al hacer clic en el botón "Restablecer contraseña", copie y pegue la URL a continuación
En su navegador web: <a href="http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #3869D4;"></a><a href="http://localhost/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #3869D4;">http://sistema.local/password/reset/250713d7beb2d72777f0af38a312c166f28dcb804cdddd01d2168115f089373d</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr></table>
</td>
                                </tr>
</table>
</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;"><tr>
<td class="content-cell" align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                    <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">© 2017 SistemaTPM. Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
        </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**PD:** no tengo ni la menor idea de donde se editan esos datos y no consigo nada en google.

Comment: Quieres cambiar localhost por sistema.local?

Comment: @Shaz si hermano, buscando conseguí que obtiene la `url` por el archivo **config/app.php** ubique 'url' y sustituí esa linea por la siguiente: `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://sistematpm.local'),`. Sin embargo, aun no me cambia la `url` en el correo.

Comment: @PabloContreras la URL se cambia en el archivo `.env` , en el apartado de  `APP_URL= `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si desea cambiar la `URL` de los emails enviados debe hacerlo en el archivo `.env` ubicado en la raíz del proyecto. El archivo `config/app.php` no se modificaría para esta operación .

Entonces su archivo `.env` en la primera sección de configuración quedaría:

```
APP_ENV=Titulo del Proyecto
APP_KEY= SU KEY
APP_DEBUG=true //depende del estado del proyecto production = false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug //depende del estado del proyecto
APP_URL= URL DEL PROYECTO

... más configuraciones ...
```

[Para personalizar el Email](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#formatting-mail-messages)  enviado por defecto en laravel 5.4 se tendría que modificar la clase `ResetPassword` , ubicada en `namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications` , pero no es correcto ya que esta clase forma parte del código fuente de laravel , por lo tanto para este caso se debería crear una Notificación para sobreescribir los métodos de `ResetPassword` , esto lo hacemos mediante el comando

```
php artisan make:notification  ResetPasswordNotification
```

Este comando creará una carpeta en `App/Notifications/ResetPasswordNotification` donde `ResetPasswordNotification` será el nombre de la clase *(puede ser otro nombre)* luego de esto , copiamos el contenido de `ResetPassword` a  `ResetPasswordNotification` , donde en el método `toMail()` sería el que modificaríamos para personalizar el `email`. No Olvidar importar la clase  en el modelo `User` , de la siguiente forma.

```
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 /* Más código*/
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Podemos cambiar el contenido. de la siguiente forma por ejemplo:

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Solicitud de reestablecimiento de contraseña') //agregamos el asunto
            ->greeting('Hola ' . $notifiable->name)// titulo del mensaje
            ->line('Recibes este email porque se solicito el reestablecimiento de contraseña para tu cuenta')
            // Action : Texto del botón , url(app.url) la tomará desde el .env  , la ruta reset con el token respectivo
            ->action('Cambiar contraseña', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
            ->line('Si no realizaste esta petición puede ignorar este correo')
            ->salutation('Saludos'); // Saludo Final
    }
```

Con esto modificariamos el cuerpo pero el pie del mensaje , donde dice que si presenta problemas y más . tendríamos que seguir otro paso adicional , desde la consola ejecutamos el comando

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Con esto nos creará una carpeta en `views/vendor/notifications` , donde estaría la parte del pie del mensaje en la parte del `component mail::subcopy` ,  para modificar de acuerdo a sus requerimientos.

```
@component('mail::subcopy')
Si usted está teniendo problemas para hacer clic en el botón "{{ $actionText }}"   copia y pega el siguiente URL en su navegador web:  [{{ $actionUrl }}]({{ $actionUrl }})
@endcomponent
```

> Todos las configuraciones del `Email` las obtiene del archivo .env

Comment: Gracias hermano, mil gracias. Funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Perfecto,  Un placer ayudar.  Saludos

Comment: Muy buena y detallada la explicación, +1

Comment: Hermano ¿Como modifico el redireccionamiento al momento de restablecer la contraseña?

Comment: @PabloContreras disculpe la demora. lo ideal hubiese sido que agregue su pregunta. cualquier otro usuario puede ayudarle. la respuesta se haría más extensa de lo que ya es.